# Compile error at static final object inside non static inner class

Tags: java, nested-class

I am new to Java and reading a book for my OCJP exam. In the book its stated *a non static inner class can have static members only if they are declared static final*. But I get compile error when I try to create a `static final object` of the container class.

```
class Logger {
    private Logger() {
        // private constructor for singleton
    }

    public class LoggerHolder { // non static inner class
        public static final int x =10; // No compile here
        public static final Logger logger = new Logger();  //Compile error
    }

    //"The field logger cannot be declared static; static fields can only be declared in static or top //level types"

    public static Logger getInstance() {
        return LoggerHolder.logger;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `logger` is not known at compile time which is why it is not allowed.

Comment: Mhh, `Logger` and `Logger4` ... where could be a problem here?

Comment: @Tom oh...sorry, my bad.... that was copying paste mistake. I edited it now...

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey.. could you please explain a little bit "why logger is not known at compile time?"... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [actual rule](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) is that the static field must be a *constant variable* - both `final` and either a primitive or a `String`. `x` is fine because `int` is a primitive; `Logger` is not.

(What a book says is just someone's opinion; for the definitive answer you can't beat the spec.)